# How to reorder a matrix according to a vector in R?

Tags: r

If I have a martix that looks like this:

```
Name <- list("A","B","C", "D")

mat <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 4)
colnames(mat) <- Name
mat
```

which produces:

```
     A B C D
[1,] 1 2 3 4
```

And I have a vector like the:

```
nameOrder <- c("B","D","A","C")
```

Is there a way to reorder the matrix columns so that the order matches that of the vector `nameOrder`? That is, the result would look something like this:

```
mat_1 <- reorder(mat columns to = nameOrder)
mat_1

    B D A C 
[1,]2 4 1 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just as the 'nameOrder' as column names

```
mat[, nameOrder, drop = FALSE]
```